# Can the layout of the test editor be changed beyond the options that it offers?

Tags: soapui

I maintain a large set of tests and recurrently add to them. when creating a REST step, the method dropdown is very narrow and it is very hard to find the desired method, especially when the path has common parts between endpoints.

Is there a hidden feature or a way to change the width that i can use to make the dropdown wider?

Any tips on how to manage long paths would be useful as well.

Maximizing the editor does not change the width.